# SQLite Objective-C: How to load the last database version?

Tags: objective-c, database, sqlite

I've got a database and the user can only read and update his tables.

I don't get how can I add new records to the tables and load the updated database in the App's Document folder without losing users' data.

Example:
Database with 2 tables:
Table A where user inserts and updates his data.
Table B which is a data source, where user can only read.

Now I want to add some new records to the Table B and upload the updated database into the App without losing data stored in Table A.

Btw, The database doesn't get copied as an older version is already stored in the Documents folder.

How can it be done?

Comment: Can't see the comment even if I got the notification :/

Answer (score 0):

A few possible considerations:

1. #### Periodic data updates between system releases

   If you're talking about ensuring the app can receive updates to table B periodically (i.e. between releases of the app), then you presumably want to design a web service to retrieve updates. If table B is not too large, design a web service that retrieves the entire contents of B in some nice format (e.g. JSON is great for this) and then write the code to contact the web service, request this data and then integrate it into the local copy of the database). If B is large, you might want to design a web service that only retrieves any creation, deletion, or update transactions.

   If you haven't done this before, I might refer you to Wenderlich's [How To Write A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for an iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app) and its companion, [How to Write an iOS App That Uses a Web Service](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service).
2. #### Migrating databases when releasing new version of app

   On the other hand, if you're talking about releasing a new version of your app, but not wanting to lose the customer information in table A, you can open both databases simultaneously (open the documents database, and then use the [`ATTACH DATABASE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) command to simultaneously open the other one in the same `sqlite3` session), and then you easily copy data from one database to the other using SQL. For example, open the new system database (with the updated table B) and attach to the database with the updated user data in table A:

   ```
   NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ATTACH DATABASE \"%@\" AS user_db", customerDbPath];
   ```

   You can then re-populate `userdata` (table A) from the `user_db` database:

   ```
   DELETE FROM userdata;
   INSERT INTO userdata SELECT * FROM user_db.userdata
   ```

   If you're doing this sort of "database migration" (integrating system updates of table B with user updates of table A), you probably want to use some control mechanism by which the system can quickly compare two databases and make sure that you know you're dealing with the same rendition of table B. You can either use the [`PRAGMA user_version`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version) for this purpose, or I personally generally have my own `configuration` table in which I'm saving general configuration information and I always have a version number in there.
3. #### Separate databases?

   One final consideration is that you might contemplate having separate databases for these two tables. This generally is not the right approach, but if you have little interaction between the two tables and if they're radically different types of data, it's another approach to consider.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. I've really appreciated it, will probably go for the second option you wrote. Thanks again, Simone.